# Flutter calendar tutorial issue SOS

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDerNqLEpPE) tutorial to make a calendar in my flutter app. For some reason, the events are not showing when you click on the date with an event:

[image]

As you can see, when I click on 9, which has an event, it is not showing as it does in the video. I am not too sure why this isn't happening as I have followed the tutorial exactly and just changed the colours.

This is the code:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRoute createState() => _SecondRoute();
}

class _SecondRoute extends State<SecondRoute> {
  CalendarController _controller;
  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _events;
  List<dynamic> _selectedEvents;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
    _events = {};
    _selectedEvents = [];
  }

  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> _groupEvents(List<EventModel> events) {
    Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> data = {};
    events.forEach((event) {
      DateTime date = DateTime(
          event.eventDate.year, event.eventDate.month, event.eventDate.day, 12);
      if (data[date] == null) data[date] = [];
      data[date].add(event);
    });
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF030164),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Calendar'),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<List<EventModel>>(
            stream: eventDBS.streamList(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<EventModel> allEvents = snapshot.data;
                if (allEvents.isNotEmpty) {
                  _events = _groupEvents(allEvents);
                }
              }
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TableCalendar(
                      events: _events,
                      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                          canEventMarkersOverflow: true,
                          todayColor: Color(0xFF974FF9),
                          selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          todayStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                        centerHeaderTitle: true,
                        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFF974FF9),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                        formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                      ),
                      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                      onDaySelected: (context, date, events) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedEvents = events;
                        });
                      },
                      builders: CalendarBuilders(
                        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) =>
                            Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                                child: Text(
                                  date.day.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                )),
                        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xFF974FF9),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                            child: Text(
                              date.day.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            )),
                      ),
                      calendarController: _controller,
                    ),
                    ..._selectedEvents.map((event) => ListTile(
                          title: Text(event.title),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => EventDetailsPage(
                                          event: event,
                                        )));
                          },
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff17F0FC),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'add_event'),
        ));
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, in `onDaySelected` the `(context, date, events)` should be ordered like `(date, events, context)` instead:

```
onDaySelected: (date, events, context) {
    setState(() {
        _selectedEvents = events;
    });
},
```